# How to Properly Manage Memory in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory

I have quite a bothersome memory issue. I'm using the package called Memory Profiler to help me try and identify the problem, but I'm not sure if I understand it properly. Basically I'm loading a map at runtime from a file, and when I load it in my actual build I get a memory snap file of around 1.2 GB in size from the Memory Profiler. But when I load the same map in a new empty project using the same code, the snap file is around 230 MB. I checked to see if the extra memory is from other stuff in the project, but if I do a memory snap before loading the map, the snap file is only 90 MB large. From what I can see in the memory map view, it looks like the extra amount is unused space I think between objects (I'm not sure, I don't know the terms very well). So my question is, if this is the case, how can I avoid this from happening. This wouldn't be an issue, but loading larger maps cause a crash.

For some reference, here are some images of the memory profiler snaps:

**Main Project Tree Map**
[image: Main Project Tree Map]

**New Project Tree Map**
[image: New Project Tree Map]

**Main Project Memory Map**
[image: Main Project Memory Map]

**New Project Memory Map**
[image: New Project Memory Map]

Answer (score 1):

Every engine pre-allocates memory for it's internal use. And yet this says nothing about cause of your particular crash.

Most memory-related crashes aren't caused by usual operations you can pick up with this memory allocation and fragmentation view.

**What you need to do instead** is to pin down the moment the crash happens and read it's stack trace for details. Because it may be the case that, for example, your problem is caused by your own code (I would bet on that) that is loading assets in some kind of loop without ever releasing that memory.

Comment: Hey Andrew! Firstly thanks for taking the time to reply, I very much appreciate it. In my post I did say what causes the crash, loading in larger maps, but you're right I need to be a lot more clear on that. When loading a large map in the fresh project, I don't get a crash (so it's for sure not stuck in a loop). When I build for android, I have a on low memory event that fires that I use to stop the loading. Before I implemented that, the larger maps caused crashing on the mobile build as well (not sure why on the windows build it doesn't fire though). I'll get an error and report back.

Comment: If this issue is about a particular android device running out of memory, then you simply won't be able to load larger levels without reducing it's memory footprint for that device (simple as that).

Comment: But please make sure it's not something code related first. Stack trace should help with that.

Comment: Your low memory event will be triggered earlier on devices that has lower amount of CPU RAM. This just means that your PC has more RAM (and virtual RAM) than that android device. This is kind of expected.

Comment: So I just got a chance to get the error, [here is a link](https://pastebin.com/sZjbjj2Q). I was re-reading your answer, and I misunderstood you. When you said the problem might be caused when loading assets during some kind of loop, for some reason I thought you were saying maybe I have an infinite loop. I definitely have a couple of different loops that load in the assets. I have the loop that loads in the faces of the map with their textures, then I have the loop that loads in models with their textures. The error seems to be happening when loading a texture. I'll have a deeper look.

Comment: How do you load these assets exactly?

Comment: `CASE A).` If your scene scripts are referencing prefabs - be aware that ALL assets in their dependency chains will become loaded into memory on scene load (pre-loaded for instant use). GOOD thing about this is that simply Instancing those prefabs won't create duplicated asset (textures etc) allocations in memory AND whose allocations will become automatically released once you change/reload your scene. So these are Unity-managed and if these are creating a memory problem then the only way to fix that is to make your assets smaller memory-wise or reference less prefabs.

Comment: `CASE B).` If you load meshes, materials and textures manually - then you're responsible for releasing them ie.: those won't ever release it's memory without your direct calls to `Destroy(asset)`. This usually happens when your project requires loading raw texture files from disc or stream via network. To fix this you need to create your own system that tracks those assets and destroys them (release memory) when they're no longer needed (or cannot be afforded to keep).

Comment: [Here is a link](https://github.com/oxters168/UnitySourceEngine/blob/6e85366e36eb3510786dd97022b96ff229bbbdf9/BSP/BSPMap.cs#L171) to the function in my github repo that is responsible for loading the map. It gets quite complicated, but I'm pretty sure I am properly deleting assets after using them since I can load many small maps (not simultaneously) without running into memory issues. The issue comes in when loading a large map, this causes the application to hang (on windows). The log gives the error I posted before when that happens.

Comment: This seems to happen when loading in the data for the assets into memory, before using that data to generate the meshes and textures. I do this so that the player doesn't get stuck while loading the map.

Comment: Ok, your code is definitely much more advanced than your question here advertises

Comment: Side quest: I see you're using Color[] - you can get rid of this allocation by using [Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html) and load byte[]s directly. This prevents unnecessary double-allocation and should make loading a bit faster

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I'm running this method on a seperate thread. Is there a way to still use this function on a separate thread, or at least do something similar that can half the textures' ram usage?

Comment: You cannot call this method from separate thread, that's unfortunately true. BUT you can make Unity thread (async) `await Task<byte[]>` results from this worker thread and only then call `LoadRawTextureData` with produced byte[].

Comment: That is an interesting idea, I only recently found out you can make the update function async. I'll try that out soon, thanks for the idea! As for the memory issue, do you think that can be caused by C#'s fragmentation?

Comment: Assuming you mean memory fragmentation - I'm not an expert on that, but from what I can deduce - this aggravates the issue but can't cause it. Ie.: memory becomes fragmented all the time, but this should prevent new allocations (which is out of memory exception).

Comment: Another detail related to how you're loading images - you're decompressing them with `Texture2DHelpers.Decompress` calls. This is indeed required for `Color[]` workflow, but (I believe) is optional for `LoadRawTextureData`, since you're loading raw bytes there. And skipping this would surely make a dent in both memory and cpu footprints

Comment: *(...) but this should**N'T** prevent new allocations (...)

Comment: **Possibly most important thing texture memory related:** don't just always call `texture.Apply()` but when all is ready call `texture.Apply( true, true )` instead. This `makeNoLongerReadable` parameter, when set to true, will release this pinned byte[] allocation from CPU RAM **MEANWHILE** leaving it's mirror copy in GPU RAM fully available for rendering (!)

Comment: Oh that reminds me, I won't be able to call LoadRawTextureData in the end because the textures are of a format Unity doesn't support. [Here's my decompression code](https://github.com/oxters168/UnityHelpers/blob/ccb005a9675056504d3e5f9ae721f796f28a5bb8/Helpers/Texture2DHelpers.cs#L69), I have it in a different repo as part of my reusable Unity code. As for the memory issue, if you're saying for sure it's not due to the fragmentation, it has to be something related to how I read textures (according to error), I'll do some digging soon try to pinpoint it. Thanks so much Andrew for all the help!

Comment: One last idea - you can create a pool of all texture headers first, sum/estimate memory footprint and compare to [available memory](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-systemMemorySize.html). If these don't fit then you create a new pool candidate where biggest textures from the previous pool are halved (executed by skipping pixel columns/rows when reading for example) or discarded/replaced. Repeat until total estimate is < device available ram, only then start reading them